# Read the inbox of a user in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-account

Is it possible to read the inbox of a user provided he/she gets authenticated via google oauth api?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Yes (from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/)) :

> Gmail supports the standard IMAP and SMTP protocols **for accessing** and sending e-mail messages. The Gmail IMAP and SMTP servers have been extended to support authorization **via the industry-standard OAuth protocol**.

Comment: @huanson Google provides samples [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/code.html) for Java, Python and PHP. The documentation detailing the protocol is available [here](http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/protocol.html). You can also use the [gmail_xoauth](https://github.com/nfo/gmail_xoauth) gem.